# How to select part of a specific css class name out of multiple classes

Tags: jquery

Given the following HTML markup:

```
<div id="my-id" class="my-class items-5"/>
```

How can I extract the `5` from the class attribute, if the `5` is generated dynamically?
I could probably do a split on the `' '` and reference the index of the `'-'` on the second index, but this seems so long winded:

```
var count = $("#my-div").attr("class").split(' ')[1].split('-')[1];
```

Comment: `items-5` is your dynamic class???

Comment: @chirag, yes, the `5` is dynamic

Comment: I suspect you don't really need to extract it BUT that's depending why would you want to extract it which you didn't give us any info about

Comment: why you are not using `data` attribute for store that dynamic value??, if you use `data` attribute , you can easily fetch that value

Comment: Do you have control over your own markup? Why not place the `5` in a data attribute instead?  `<div id="my-id" class="my-class items-5" data-key="5"/>` and in jQuery -> `var key = $(".my-class").data("key");`

Comment: @A.Wolff, the `5` is bound on the View, which I need to reference client-side. The value of the extracted `item-?` class will be used for other client-side processing.

Comment: @RudolfLamprecht , can you try that `data` attribute solution ??

Comment: @RudolfLamprecht so as i understand it, you need to use data-* attribute not class, as suggested above

Comment: I don't really have control over how the markup is generated, that is why I aimed for the class route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution for a fixed markup that you can't change, and assuming that the relevant class is always `items-number` is to split by `items-`, and then get the first word after it:

```js
var count = $("#my-id").attr("class").split('items-')[1].split(' ')[0];
console.log(count);

var count2 = $("#my-id2").attr("class").split('items-')[1].split(' ')[0];
console.log(count2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="my-id" class="my-class items-5"/>
<div id="my-id2" class="my-class items-23 another-class"/>
```

This would also work for more classes and different orderings.

Answer (score 0):

Considering it's a single digit.

```js
var divClass = $("#my-div").attr("class");
var digit = divClass.substr(-1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="my-div" class="my-class items-5"/>
```

Comment: This would work if `items-5` is always the last class. It could be that there are other classes after `items-5`, eg: `class="my-class items-5 another-class"`

Comment: True. This is an alternative to your solution given the HTML example above. For other markup indexOf and split will play better.

Answer (score 0):

try this one 
https://jsfiddle.net/fm7dp4ht/

```
var count;
var parsed;
var classList = document.getElementById('my-id').className.split(/\s+/);
for (var i = 0; i < classList.length; i++) {
    if (parsed = classList[i].match(/^items-([0-9]*)$/)) {
        count = parsed[1];
        break;
    }
}
alert(count);
```